# C# How to connect with public ip

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Hello im learning how to write application using sockets, there is my question. How can i make a connection now just in LAN, i mean.. i will send my client app to my friend and he will be able connect to my server. 
there is code:

client:

```
Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.31.87"), 56597));
sck.Listen(100);//maksymalna ilosc polaczen oczekujacych

Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
byte[] Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];

int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);


byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];


for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
     formatted[i] = Buffer[i];


string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");

Console.Read();

sck.Close();
```

server:

```
Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.31.87"), 56597)); //yes i censored ip.
sck.Listen(100);//maksymalna ilosc polaczen oczekujacych

Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
byte[] Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];

int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);


byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];


for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        formatted[i] = Buffer[i];


string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");

Console.Read();

sck.Close();
```

I did port forwarding but when i want write to IPEndPoint my address this give me error like invalid ip.

Comment: How can i make a connection NOT just in LAN*******************

Comment: Are you using your public IP? Or the LAN IP?

Comment: Is your friend behind a router? If so, then he'll probably need to port-forward whichever port you use.

Comment: @DawidKacprzak - Click the "edit" button below your question to change it. You shouldn't comment fixes to your post.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to bind your server to a public IP (the one your router got assigned by your ISP). That will work only on the client side, or if the computer the server is running on is directly connected to the internet with a public IP (very unlikely). The server needs to bind to its internal LAN IP, then the router on the server side needs to forward any connections to that internal IP.

Comment: I wanted to write ip from ipchicken, my friend is in other city co behind router

Comment: Okay, so i wrote 127.0.0.1 on server. what now?

Comment: i want connect with port 56597, my LAN ip is 192.168.1.251 my forwarding options are Public port range - 56590-56599 Target ip address 192.168.1.251 target port range 56590-56599 Protocol UDP and tcp.

Comment: The one of you who will be the "listener" (aka server) for the incoming connection must port forward and preferrably listen to `IPAddress.Any` (which is the same as `0.0.0.0`). Then the person who connects to the other must know the other person's public IP, which can be found using a website like http://whatsmyip.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting endpoints by resolving through a DNS on both the client and server

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 56597);
```

and

```
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,  
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
```

Make sure port-forwarding is done both on the client and server if behind routers and/or firewalls.

Take a look through MS examples:

- [Socket Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Socket Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx)

[C# Sockets over the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700466/c-sharp-sockets-over-the-internet) has some troubleshooting tips for sockets over internet!